# Kafka sending Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

hello i want to send a message from producer and received in consumer as capitalized. using CONFLUENT and KAFKA with a build.gradle file and StreamingApp.java containing this codes:

```
ProcessingApp.java:

package kafka_stream;


import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;

import java.util.Properties;


public class StreamingApp { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"streaming_app_id");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");

StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(props);
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

Topology topology = builder.build();

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology,config);

KStream<String, String> simpleFirstStream = builder.stream("src-topic");
KStream<String, String> upperCasedStream = simpleFirstStream.mapValues(String::toUpperCase);

upperCasedStream.to("out-topic");

System.out.println("Streaming App Started");
streams.start();
Thread.sleep(30000);
System.out.println("shutting downl the streaming app");
streams.close();

}
}
```

so hot to get this option solved?

Comment: Check out the quickstart: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html -- It explains how to create a local Kafka cluster for testing, and how to write input data for a Kafka Streams application.